# Combobox selected item is deleted once selected . Invalid Postback or Callback argument

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have four textboxes one combobox and one button ( and some other controls) in my page . Based on the values typed in the textboxes the related values are updated in the  combobox. On clicking the submit button in my page It was giving the following error .

> > "Invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled using in configuration or in a page. For Secuity purposes,this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them. If the data is valid and expected . Use the `ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventsValidation` method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation."

Now in the page directive I added

```
<%@Page EnableEentValidation="false">
```

When I type the values in the four  textboxes the corresponding value will appear in the cobobox . But when I select that combobox value, the selected value wil be deleted . What is the reason for this ?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Main.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AddeChecklist.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="LabTrack.WebApplication.Echecklist.AddeChecklist" EnableEventValidation ="false" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="Labinal" TagName="AutoCompleteControl" Src="~/UserControls/AutoCompleteEnabledWebUserControl.ascx" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    <link href="../Styles/CheckListRev.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Style for the page -->
    <link href="../Styles/AddeChecklist.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePartialRendering="true" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:Panel ID="ErrorMessagePanel" CssClass="ErrorPanel" Visible="true" runat="server">
        <div class="ErrorDiv">
            <asp:BulletedList CssClass="ErrorMessage" ID="ErrorMessageBulletedList" runat="server">
            </asp:BulletedList>
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
    <div class="PageTitle">
        <asp:Label ID="PageHeaderLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div class="MainDiv">
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <div class="PlaceHolder">
                <table id="formTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatepanelCustomer" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <span class="boldLabelLong">Customer:</span><br />
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="CustomerNameTextBox" Width="200" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="IxCustomerHiddenField" runat="server" />
                                    <asp:Button ID="customerTriggerbutton" runat="server" Text="Button" Style="display: none;" />
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatepanelProgram" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <span class="boldLabelLong">Program:</span><br />
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="ProgramNameTextBox" Width="200" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:Button ID="programTriggerbutton" runat="server" Text="Button" Style="display: none;" />
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="IxProgramHiddenField" runat="server" />
                                </ContentTemplate>
                                <Triggers>
                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="customerTriggerbutton" EventName="Click" />
                                </Triggers>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatepanelWorkPackage" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <span class="boldLabelLong">WorkPackage:</span><br />
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="WorkPackageNameTextBox" Width="200" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="IxWorkPackageHiddenField" runat="server" />
                                    <asp:Button ID="workPackageTriggerbutton" runat="server" Text="Button" Style="display: none;" />
                                </ContentTemplate>
                                <Triggers>
                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="programTriggerbutton" EventName="Click" />
                                </Triggers>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatepanelActivity" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <span class="boldLabelLong">Activity:</span><br />
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="ActivityNameTextBox" Width="200" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="IxActivityHiddenField" runat="server" />
                                    <asp:Button ID="activityTriggerbutton" runat="server" Text="Button" Style="display: none;" />
                                </ContentTemplate>
                                <Triggers>
                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="workPackageTriggerbutton" EventName="Click" />
                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="activityTriggerbutton" EventName="Click" />
                                </Triggers>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="PlaceHolder">
                <asp:Label ID="TemplateLabel" Text="Template:" CssClass="ControlLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatepanelTemplate" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="TemplateSelectDropDownList" runat="server" Width="400" Visible="true"
                            AutoPostBack="true">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="IxTemplateHiddenField" runat="server" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="workPackageTriggerbutton" EventName="Click" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                <asp:Panel ID="SustainPanelTemplateOwner" Visible="true" runat="server">
                    <div>
                        <asp:Label ID="TemplateOwnerLabel" Text="Owner:" CssClass="ControlLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TemplateOwnerTextBox" CssClass="controlMargin" Width="400" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </asp:Panel>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="IxDeliverableHiddenField" runat="server" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="IxReleaseActionHiddenField" runat="server" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="IxConfigHiddenField" runat="server" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="IxTemplateOwnerHiddenField" runat="server" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="TemplateSelectedSnameHiddenField" runat="server" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="TemplateOwnerSelectedsNameHiddenField" runat="server" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="DeliverableSelectedHiddenField" runat="server" />
                <div>
                    <asp:Label ID="DeliverableLabel" CssClass="ControlLabel" runat="server" Text="Deliverable:"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="DeliverableTextBox" CssClass="controlMargin" Width="400" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <asp:Panel ID="SustainPanelConfig" Visible="true" runat="server">
                    <div>
                        <asp:Label ID="ConfigurationLabel" runat="server" Text="Configuration:" CssClass="ControlLabel"></asp:Label>
                        <select id="ConfigurationSelect" class="controlMargin">
                            <option></option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel ID="SustainPanelRelease" Visible="true" runat="server">
                    <div>
                        <asp:Label ID="ReleaseActionLabel" CssClass="ControlLabel" runat="server" Text="Release Action:"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="ReleaseActionTextBox" CssClass="controlMargin" Width="400" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel ID="SustainPanel" Visible="true" runat="server">
                    <div class="SustainPanelControls">
                        <div>
                            <asp:Label ID="ChangeLabel" Text="Change #: " runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="ChangeTextBox" Width="110" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <asp:Label ID="SupplementLabel" Text="Supplement: " runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="SupplementTextBox" Width="80" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <asp:Label ID="NewWrrLabel" Text="WRR #: " runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="NewWrrTextBox" Width="80" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <asp:Label ID="DddLabel" Text="3D: " runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="DddTextBox" Width="80" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <table id="DesignDataTable2">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="AllFbSheetsWrrLabel" Text="All F/B Sheets w/WRR #:" CssClass="ControlLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="completeControl" ID="AllFbSheetsWrrTextBox" Width="588" Rows="2"
                                        TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </asp:Panel>
            </div>
            <div class="EditButtonGroup">
                <input id="EditButton" type="button" value="Edit" class="ButtonSettings" />
                <input id="RemoveButton" type="button" value="-" class="ButtonSettings" />
                <input id="AddButton" type="button" value="+" class="ButtonSettings" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ViewData">
            <div class="ViewDataDiv">
                <table id="DesignDataTable" class="designDataTable">
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="submitButtonDiv">
            <asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" Text="Button Text" class="submitButtonCreateChecklist" />
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: The same copy of code works fine in another pc !  Internet Explorer Version 8 which is same as mine .

Comment: Once select a value from combobox will give message"MS JScript RT error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:nvalid postback/callback argument.Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in config or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If data is valid & expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method inorderto register postback/callback data for validation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating new values on the client side, and posting them back to the server.

For security reasons ASP.NET implements "event validation". When even validation is enabled, if the server creates a combo with 3 possible values, it will only accept this values on postback. If you create a different value and send it back to the server, you get the error you're referring to.

Here you have some info:
[Page.EnableEventValidation Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableeventvalidation.aspx)

You can use [ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerforeventvalidation.aspx) if you know which are the possible values generated on the client side, or disable validation completely if you don't know them in advance.

To disable validation:

> > You set the EnableEventValidation property by setting the enableEventValidation attribute of the @ Page directive or the enableEventValidation attribute of the pages element in the Web.config file. If you set this property in code, you must set it before the page is initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an issue with Viewstate overriding the values.

Try fetching the value directly using `Request.Form[Dropdown.ClientId]`